# Test service with 3rd party API calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I have a service with business logic and http calls (using Unirest) to a third party service.

public PaymentLinkResult generatePaymentLink(PaymentLinkParams paymentLinkParams) throws GatewayException {

```
    // BUSINESS LOGIC

    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response;
    try (UnirestInstance service = Unirest.spawnInstance()) {
        response = service.post(apiBaseUrl + "/api/v1/openOrder.do")
                .body(body)
                .asJson();
    }

    if (response.getBody() == null) {
        // BUSINESS LOGIC
    }

    // BUSINESS LOGIC
}
```

I created a test for this service,  my goal is to test the business logic without making a real HTTP call to the 3rd party service. Basically i want to test if the request is created correctly and if the output is correct.

I'm struggling to find the best way to handle this scenario with Spring Boot. I know how to mock the entire method but i would like to mock only the HTTP call part.

Comment: Could that be of help? https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/tree/main/unirest-mocks

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose it's incredible how i saw this library yesterday and i totally tought it was not what I was looking for... I tested this but it was not working because i was using spawnInstance method. It probably works only with the base static instance. Using the static instance works so thank you.